# Java (Eclipse) Class return statements not working

Tags: java, eclipse, class, testing, return

I am writing a class that among other things creates accessors and mutators. However when I run my program to make use of the class nothing is being returned, or well my program does not output anything.

In test program (below) I create class variables and send them to the class where I input and then returned the variable.

My ideal output would be for the function calls to return the variable. 
For instance the (getLatitude would output the Latitude variable)

**Here is my class code:**

```
package practiceProblems;

import stdlib.StdOut;

public class GPSPosition implements Comparable <GPSPosition> {

    // Private global variables
    private Double Latitude;
    private Double Longitude;
    private Double Altitude;

    // Constructor 1
    public <Item extends Comparable<? super Item>> GPSPosition() { 
        Latitude  = 0.0; 
        Longitude = 0.0; 
    }

    // Constructor 2
    public <Item extends Comparable<? super Item>> GPSPosition (Double lat, Double lon, Double alt) {
        this.Altitude  = alt;
        this.Latitude  = lat;
        this.Longitude = lon;

        if (lat < -90 || lat > 90) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("NOPE!");
        }

        if (lon < -180 || lon > 180) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("NOPE!!");
        }

        if (alt < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("NOPE!!!");
        }
    }

    // Latitude Accessor
    public Double getLatitude () { 
        return this.Latitude; 
    }

    // Longitude Accessor
    public Double getLongitute () { 
        return this.Longitude; 
    }

    // Altitude Accessor
    public Double getAltutude () { 
       return this.Altitude; 
    }

    // Mutator for Latitude
    public void setLatitude (Double Latitude) { 
        this.Latitude = Latitude;
    }

    // Mutator for Longitude
    public void setLongitude (Double Longitude) { 
        this.Longitude = Longitude;
    }

    // Mutator for Altitude
    public void setAltitude (Double Altitude) { 
        this.Altitude = Altitude;
    }

    // Compare to method
    public int compareTo (GPSPosition that) {
        if (this.Latitude.compareTo (that.Latitude) > 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (this.Latitude.compareTo (that.Latitude) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        return that.Latitude.compareTo (this.Latitude);
    }

    // toString method
    public String toString () {
        String latOutput  = "";
        String longOutput = "";

        if (this.Latitude < 0) { 
            latOutput = "S"; 
        } else {
            latOutput = "N";
        }

        if (this.Longitude < 0) { 
            latOutput = "W"; 
        } else {
            latOutput = "E";
        }

        return (this.Latitude + latOutput + " " + this.Longitude + longOutput + " " + this.Altitude + "m");
    }

    public double distance (GPSPosition that) {
        return (Math.sqrt ((this.Latitude - this.Longitude) + (that.Longitude - that.Latitude)));
    }   
}
```

**Here is my test program:**

```
package practiceProblems;

import practiceProblems.GPSPosition;

public class TestGPS {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // Positions
        GPSPosition position  = new GPSPosition (-37.2, 87.2, 200.0);   
        GPSPosition position2 = new GPSPosition (37.2, 7.2, 100.0); 

        // Set
        position.setAltitude (200.0); 
        position.setLatitude (-37.2);
        position.setLongitude (87.2);

        // Get
        position.getAltutude (); 
        position.getLatitude (); 
        position.getLongitute ();

        // Compare to
        position.compareTo (position2);

        // To String call
        position.toString ();

        // Distance between two positions
        position.distance (position2);  
    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: All of the return statements?

Comment: But you have to declare variables for that, like `String positionStr = position.toString();`

Comment: `return` statements don't print things to StdOut on their own.

Comment: I'm a little confused, so you mean instead of just returning the variable, do something more like: (return this.Latitude.toString();) ?

Is that not what the toString method does?

Comment: Return calls do not print anything, they are used as the "result" of a function. The `toString()` method does not print anything either, it simply returns a String. If you want to print something to Eclipse's console, you must use `System.out.println()`. You could do something like `System.out.println(position.toString())`. If you want `getLatitude()` and other methods to print their return value too, you can put a call to `System.out.println` just before the return statement (everything after the return statement is not executed).

Comment: What is the point of the ToString method then? If I need to manually tell my code to StdOut.println.... If I return the variable in the get method does that not then print out when I call the toString method?

Comment: @Andrew `toString` is a method that returns a `textual` representation of the object (which is a `String`). Now that you have this `String`, you can do whatever you want with it: including a `print`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like the following in your main method:

```
public class TestGPS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Positions
        GPSPosition position = new GPSPosition(-37.2, 87.2, 200.0); 
        GPSPosition position2 = new GPSPosition(37.2, 7.2, 100.0);  

        // Set
        position.setAltitude(200.0); position.setLatitude(-37.2);
        position.setLongitude(87.2);

        // Get
        System.out.println("Altitude:  " + position.getAltutude()); 
        System.out.println("Latitude:  " + position.getLatitude()); 
        System.out.println("Longitude: " + position.getLongitute());

        // Compare to
        System.out.println("Comparison: " + position.compareTo(position2));

        // To String call
        System.out.println("Position: " + position.toString());

        // Distance between two positions
        System.out.println("Distance: " + position.distance(position2));   

    }
```

However, note that your distance method doesn't return a number, NaN stands for "Not a Number".

Comment: This makes so much sense. I tried it and it worked!

However I think I am confused as to what exactly the return statement actually does. Which is why I was not sure why it was printing.

Comment: return statements are using to report back to the calling code, either no value or some value, depending on whether "return" has an argument. If it has an argument, that value is "returned" to the caller. This might help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
One last thing if you wouldnt mind: How did you know that my distance method was going to give me a NaN?
I changed the code a little:

(
 `double distance = Math.sqrt((this.Latitude - this.Longitude) + (that.Longitude - that.Latitude)); 
  return distance;`
)

Comment: I didn't. I got NaN when I ran the code that I posted above.